# Set iPhone volume to maximum when connecting to a Bluetooth speaker

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones, speakers

Normally I like to keep my iPhone volume quite low, so that when audio plays, it isn't too loud at first.

However, when I connect my iPhone to a Bluetooth speaker, I want the iPhone's volume to be maximum, so that the audio that gets outputted to the speakers isn't too soft, and I can from then on control the audio with the speakers instead of the iPhone.

Is it possible to have the iPhone automatically increase its volume to maximum only when connecting to Bluetooth speakers?

For instance, when attaching headphones to the iPhone, it has a different volume setting for them, versus without headphones. I'd like something similar when connecting Bluetooth speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth volume is set independently of internal speaker volume.

Same control, the +/- buttons on the side of the iDevice, but once you are streaming to bluetooth, the actual control is then adjusting Bluetooth send volume, not speaker volume.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I was unfamiliar with Bluetooth devices connected to iPhone.

Comment: What is Bluetooth send volume, though?  At max, is it full line level that an amplifier (speaker volume control) can safely amplify? Or, is max Bluetooth prone to distorting and the real natural line level (like a DAC or CD player would supply) is Bluetooth 50% (for example)?

Answer (score 2):

Some Bluetooth speakers use the phone volume control to determine the speaker volume which is much simpler than having 2 independent volumes. It works both ways too, if using volume buttons on the speaker then the iPhone volume slider updates instantly. Its similar to how using line-out was better than headphone for connecting speakers via a cable in the old days. I'd suggest trying a speaker with that feature and see if it works better for you, like the Anker Sound Core Sport for example. The Amazon Echo and Sony devices don't have it unfortunately. I'm not sure if it remembers the volume level but think it does.

Update:
This feature is called Absolute Volume Control and was added in the Bluetooth spec AVRCP v1.4 so look for devices that support that.